# How can I make a window in 100% height and width with ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

This one didn't work:

```
new Ext.Window({
    width:'100%',
    height: '100%'
}).show();
```

I has do be fluid, so that when the window is resized it has to change its diemensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be achieved by creating a Viewport, which is designed to do exactly what you're asking. Here's a quick example, and it shows that you don't need to specify any heights/widths:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var thisView = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'anchor',
        items:[
            {   title: 'Section 1'
                ,html: 'some content'
            }
            ,{  title: 'Section 2'
                ,html: 'some more content'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

You'll note that you don't even need to "show" it.

EDIT: Oh, I meant to also remark that if you add some longer content into those html sections, you'll see that if you resize your browser window, they will change their heights automatically to let all the content be seen.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Will view port be similar to a window ? Window is some thing that pops out and viewport just renders the component to the body of the document. Correct me if I am wrong !

Comment: window and viewport can be use at the same time

Answer (score 4):

This can only be achieved by monitoring `window.resize` event.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var win = new Ext.Window({
        draggable: false
    });

    win.show();

    win.setSize(Ext.getBody().getViewSize());
    win.setPagePosition(0, 0);
    Ext.fly(window).on('resize', function(e, w) {
        win.setSize(Ext.getBody().getViewSize());
        win.setPagePosition(0, 0);
    });
});
```

Notice that my example works properly if `body` has `overflow: hidden`. Otherwise unwanted scrollbars will be shown.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/MVewR/).